# C# OPCUA - sessin Read in subscription.FastDataChangeCallback failed due to connection

Tags: c#

I have a subscription, but I need to read all monitored items even not changed. Sometimes I get a `KeepAlive` event, so I start `BeginReconnect`, but before the `ReconnectComplete` event I get the `FastDataChangeCallback` event and when I call session. Read it fail on the bad session and I lose data in this change. (from KeepAlive event to `ReconnectComplete` event elapse even 10 on more seconds)

How to solve safe reading all items in the `FastDataChangeCallback` handler? Maybe some while on reading till the `ReconnectComplete` event to occur? I never found a similar situation because all read-only changed monitored items from `DataChangeNotification`, but I need all from the given structure.

Comment: what sdk or library are you using?

Comment: OPCFoundation.NetStandard v 1.4.357.28  nuget package for VS